# Merged Manifest en Android Studio

Tags: android

Porque en el Merged Manifest veo el `minSdkVersion` y el `targetSdkVersion` con otros valores diferentes al AndroidManifest de mi app?

[image: Manifest de la app]
[image: Merged Manifest]

Estuve investigando y entiendo que al compilarse la app, se genera un AndroidManifest definitivo, de entre todos los que puedan haber en el proyecto.

De la lista Manifest Sources, hice click en cada uno de los links y cambie los valores en cada archivo a `minSdkVersion="9"` y `targetSdkVersion="23"` y `versionCode="12"`, tal como quiero que quede finalmente para poder subirlo a la tienda. Pero el Merged Manifest sigue igual..

¿Qué debo hacer?
Gracias.

Comment: Agrega tu build.gradle Josue,

Comment: en android studio se usa gradle y lo que allí defines machacara los valores que pongas directamente androidmanifest

Answer (score 1):

Porque estos valores son sobreescritos por los valores declarados dentro del `build.gradle` del proyecto.

En realidad puedes definir  `minSdkVersion` y `targetSdkVersion` en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` pero si defines estos valores también dentro de tu `build.gradle`, estos valores son sobreescritos, estos son los valores que ves en tu Merged Manifest.

Comment: Gracias!! Eso lo solucionó! Esos valores estaban casi al final del build.gradle por eso no los encontraba.-